# GraphQL Query via cURL -- Unexpected <EOF> error

Tags: curl, graphql

I'm passing this through Insomnia client with no issues and data returned:

`{  "query": "{purchaseOrders{poNumber}}"}`

However, when I am trying to push it through curl I'm getting an error. Here is my curl command:

`curl -X POST -g -H "Authorization:Bearer token"  -H "content-type:application/json" -H "accept:application/json" -d '{"query":"{purchaseOrders{poNumber}}"}' https://api.wayfair.com/v1/graphql`

I am getting the following error:

`{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error GraphQL (1:1) Unexpected <EOF>\n\n1: \n   ^\
n","category":"graphql","locations":[{"line":1,"column":1}]}]}`

I am not seeing examples that are fashioned like this, and am having success with the API clients, so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Edit to include the POST request:

```
POST /v1/graphql HTTP/1.1
Host: api.wayfair.com
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: bf83f6be-a560-43b8-8519-6f05a6a60f83

{"query":"{purchaseOrders{poNumber}}"}
```

Comment: Are you receiving the payload as body data? On the client, how it was sent ? payload format. The error is `Unexpected <EOF>`, something is missing in your body data. The `\n` belongs to error message.

Comment: Also, if you want to use a curl like CLI tool for graphql, have you taken a look at https://github.com/hasura/graphqurl ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue:

`{"query":"{purchaseOrders{poNumber}}"}`

Should be:

`{\"query\": \"query { purchaseOrders { poNumber }}\" }`

This is now working, with the additional query verb

Answer (score 0):

Some GraphQL clients request adicional fields on request as `variables` and `operationName`.

Example of body:

```
{"query":"{purchaseOrders{poNumber}}", "variables":null, "operationName":null}"
```

Comment: Do you have some example of the body sent by client? If are you using it on browser, you can get it on network tab.

Comment: Let me get that and add to my question.  Thank you!